# ActionBar hidden when starting fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an activity that correctly displays my ActionBar and it's items, however when I try to add a fragment to that activity the ActionBar disappears when that fragment is launched, or if I try to include the ActionBar it shows the bar but no title or MenuOptions.

Want I am trying to achieve is one activity, with the same ActionBar for all fragments, unless specified otherwise.

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_container, homeFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.search_mag_icon){
        // Open intent here
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Book icon and text -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookIcon"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dip"
            android:src="@drawable/book" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bookIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:text="@string/bookLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <!-- Barcode icon and text -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/barcodeIcon"
            android:layout_width="95dip"
            android:layout_height="95dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dip"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/barcodeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/barcodeIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:text="@string/barcodeLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <!-- Message icon and text -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="350dip"
            android:src="@drawable/email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
            android:text="@string/messageLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- List icon and text -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listIcon"
            android:layout_width="95dip"
            android:layout_height="95dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="350dip"
            android:src="@drawable/list" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="273dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:text="@string/listLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFF"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Book icon and text -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/book"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:layout_marginTop = "110dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bookLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bookLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bookIcon" />


<!-- Barcode icon and text -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/barcodeIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/barcode"
    android:layout_width="95dip"
    android:layout_height="95dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="260dip"
    android:layout_marginTop = "120dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/barcodeLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/barcodeLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/barcodeIcon"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="260dip"/>


<!-- Message icon and text -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/messageIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/email"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:layout_marginTop = "350dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/messageLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/messageIcon" />

<!-- List icon and text -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/list"
    android:layout_width="95dip"
    android:layout_height="95dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="260dip"
    android:layout_marginTop = "350dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/listLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listIcon"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="273dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Show your xml code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify layout

Put you `ToolBar` inside `LinearLayout` and Change `Fragment` with `FrameLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

call `Fragment` from `Activity`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,homeFragment));
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did that but now the activity launches without the fragment being launched/placed on the screen, another problem with the layouts?

Comment: Still doesn't work =/ I changed the imported library to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; to solve the compatibility error, but the fragment still does not show.

Comment: `fragment_home` layout ??. should not be empty

Comment: I have updated the original post, was that code snippet you posted meant to go into the activity_main or fragment_home? Sorry if i've misunderstood.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct and re-submitted a new question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571336/fragment-added-to-activity-but-does-not-show